# How to convert Firebase.Messaging.Remotemessage to string

Tags: c#, firebase, type-conversion, firebase-cloud-messaging

I need to convert Firebase.Messaging.RemoteMessage to string. I tried this :

```
string message0;
        message0 = Convert.ToString(message);
        mainPage.StepThree(message0);
```

And this :

```
 mainPage.StepThree((string)message);
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: Based on the documentation getData() seems to be what you are after.  It will return a Map<string, string>, which you iterate over using the keys from the map.  I have never used firebase before though.

Comment: Isn't that from Java ? Also it says : getData doesn't exist in current context.

Comment: I mean getData()

Comment: Yes you are correct, my mistake.  Looking at the C# reference it looks like you want to use RawData `This field is only used for downstream messages received through the FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived event.`  It might be worth look at the key/value pairs inside of `Data` as well, since if the message does exist there it will already be a string.

Comment: Thanks. How can I use RawData or Data ? Can you please send me the source ?

Comment: I was looking at the Unity reference for Firebase which can be found here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/messaging/firebase-messaging  Other API references are found on the left under the appropriate section

Comment: Data is a Dictionary<string, string> and would be used by checking the value present for a given key.  You can get the keys from the dictionary using Data.Keys, and can be used in a for/each loop,  foreach (var key in Data.Keys) { var thisValue = Data[key]; }

Comment: I posted the wrong link, i was looking at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/messaging/firebase-message

Comment: OK thanks. I'm still kinda confused how to use it. Do I need to type something like FirebaseMessaging.Data ? Or how is it usable in the code ?

Comment: message is an instance of Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessage correct?  so it would be `message.Data` and `message.RawData` respecfully.  I would first check all of the keys and associated values in the Data dictionary to see if the message is in there (since it would already be a string).  When using RawData, you would need to convert the byte[] to a string, plenty of examples of that here on stackoverflow.

Comment: You're welcome.